# How to filter the follwing query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am using the following search:

```
{
    "_source": [
        "title",
        "bench",
        "court",
        "id_"
    ],
    "size": 10,
    "query": {

        "bool": {
            "must": {

                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "murder" 
                    ,
                    "fields": [
                        "title",
                        "content"
                    ]
                }
            },

            "should": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "murder",
                    "fields": [
                        "title.standard",
                        "content.standard"
                    ]
                }
            }

        }


    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "title": {},
            "content": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I now want to filter the results using the id (`_id`) elastic search gave it during indexing. For example, {`"_id" : 5903`}. I guess you have to use the term query. The results should be such that only if the `_id` is matched, the document returns. How can I do that?

Comment: Is https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-ids-query.html what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool, for all the people haveing the same need, I've created the answer in order to mark this question as solved. Please feel free to resolve it by accepting the answer. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get your query filtered by doc's id (one, or many), there is a special id query in elasticsearch. Here are the details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-ids-query.html